Re-do paint over mould-affected walls
I really liked the two in-depth answers to this question about preparing a surface for painting in a bathroom.
As a DIY beginner, I don't realise the importance of using particular products and things like priming, mist coats, permeable layers, etc.
I have some walls that have been affected by mould from high humidity. The mould varies from oily looking patches to black mould that has been cleaned off thoroughly with HG mould spray.


Now the walls are cleaned and ready for repainting, what are my next steps? What are the best quality products to use and what's the best course of action to prevent this reoccurring? We now have a better understanding of ventilate and use dehumidifiers regularly.
I am already using Owatrol VC175 paint additive. Is B-I-N or similar recommended to stop the stains showing through?

All paint jobs require good surface prep.  Usually just a very good cleaning of dust/dirt/oil and sometimes also a light sanding for glossy paint plus more cleaning.  Prep is the hard part of painting.

@crip659 So a soap wash and sanding is all that is required?

TSP or similar is usually recommended since it removes oil(skin, cooking) also.  You want nothing on the surface except old well bonded clean paint.  New paint/primer will bond to the first thing it touches, so you want it to touch solid well bonded paint/primer and not dirt/dust/oil/loose paint which will cause new paint fall off.

@crip659 and should I just paint the wall paint straight on? And no other additives?

If stains you want a stain hider as the primer to reduce the number of paint coats needed to cover.

@crip659 and what is the best in industry stain hider to use as primer?
